# How do I prevent dark mode from resetting when loading page?

Tags: javascript

I read that either local storage or session storage would do the trick, but I'm having a hard time trying to make it work.

```
function changeStyleByClass(className, classToggle){
var element = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
for (var i=0; i < element.length; i++) {
    element[i].classList.toggle(classToggle);
}}
document.getElementById("bulb").addEventListener("click", () => {
changeStyleByClass("bgcolor-lightdark", "dark-mode");
changeStyleByClass("nav", "dark-mode");
changeStyleByClass("nav-item", "dark-mode");
changeStyleByClass("card", "dark-mode");
changeStyleByClass("container", "dark-mode");
changeStyleByClass("bulbicon","dark-mode");});
```

I'd like to navigate through pages and still keep the theme that is currently on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code here as text, not an image.

Comment: How are you serving your pages? Do you use a server / framework with server side rendering? Do you render client side with a library? Or is it plain html, cs, js pages?

Comment: Edited.

Just plain html, css and js pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `localStorage.setItem` to store data and `localStorage.getItem` to retrieve data. One thing that I've noticed is that your light bulb button turns dark mode on, but doesn't turn dark mode off. I have a solution that also simplifies your process of changing themes.

```js
var togButton = document.getElementById("togButton");

//Check localStorage
//It's commented out because it doesn't work in Stack Overflow snippet
//darkOn = localStorage.getItem("dark") == "true" ? true : false;
setTheme();

function setTheme(){
  //Save to localStorage
  //It's commented out because it doesn't work in Stack Overflow snippet
  //localStorage.setItem("dark", darkOn ? "true" : "false");
  if(darkOn){
    document.body.setAttribute("theme", "dark");
    togButton.innerHTML = "Turn off dark mode.";
  }
  else{
    document.body.setAttribute("theme", "light");
    togButton.innerHTML = "Turn on dark mode.";
  }
}

var darkOn = false;
function toggle(){
  darkOn = !darkOn;
  setTheme();
}

togButton.addEventListener("click", toggle);
```

```css
/*By doing body[theme=dark] it only takes effect if the <body> tag has an attribute called theme which is dark.*/

body[theme=light] .sampleClass{
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

body[theme=dark] .sampleClass{
  color: mediumseagreen;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="sampleClass">Theme changes.</h1>
  <button id="togButton">Turn on dark mode.</button>
</body>
```

This method is easier because you don't need to manually type all of the classes you want to turn to dark mode, you can just have bot dark and light modes in the CSS file.

I hope you understand the javascript + css. Good luck and ask me if you can't understand part of it.

Edit: Called `setTheme()` right away.

Edit 2: Explanation

The part which is `localStorage.getItem("dark") == "true" ? true : false"` is called turnary. The turnary syntax is *condition* ? *value if true* : *value if false*. It is basically the same thing as doing

```
if(localStorage.getItem("dark") == "true"){
    darkOn = true;
}
else{
    darkOn = false;
}
```

This is because localStorage is like a `Map` where the keys and values are both strings.

Moving on to the next part.
`darkOn = false;` Just declares the variable `darkOn` and by default it if `false`. The toggle function changes `darkOn` to be the opposite of what it is. the exclamation mark negates boolean values, so `darkOn = !darkOn;` turns `darkOn` to `false` if it was previously `true`, and `true` if it was previously false.

Then it calls the `setTheme` function to update the `theme` attribute in the `<body>` tag, causing the css to change. It also saves the current value to `localStorage`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. First, what I don't understand is this: "true" ? true : false;  in the local storage and the reason why the function is called below. Second, I don't understand this part:

var darkOn = false;
function toggle(){
  darkOn = !darkOn;
  setTheme();

Comment: I edited the answer to further explain. This article may help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for your help and clarification!