# Dark mode gets turned off on refreshing a page

Tags: javascript

```
function darkMode() {
  var element = document.body;
  var content = document.getElementById("DarkModetext");
  element.className = "darkmode11"
  content.innerText = "Dark Mode is ON"
  content.style.color = "white"
}
function lightMode() {
  var element = document.body
  var content = document.getElementById("DarkModetext")
  content.innerText = "Dark Mode is OFF"
  element.className = "lightmode11"
  content.style.color = "black"
}
```

//I have made two function one is for darkmode and another is for light mode the problem is when i turn on the dark mode and refresh the page the dark mode get turned off

Comment: You need to save somewhere that you have dark mode turned on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent dark mode from resetting when loading page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758979/how-do-i-prevent-dark-mode-from-resetting-when-loading-page)

Answer (score 2):

You have to save mode setting somewhere like cookies or localStorage.
Code below does this for you hope this is helpful.
script type='module' means this script runs before page load so page doesnt flash white to black.

```
    <script type="module">
if(localStorage.getItem('mode') == 'dark'){
    darkmode();
    }

    function darkMode() {
      localStorage.setItem("mode","dark");
      var element = document.body;
      var content = document.getElementById("DarkModetext");
      element.className = "darkmode11"
      content.innerText = "Dark Mode is ON"
      content.style.color = "white"
    }
    function lightMode() {
      localStorage.setItem("mode","light");
      var element = document.body
      var content = document.getElementById("DarkModetext")
      content.innerText = "Dark Mode is OFF"
      element.className = "lightmode11"
      content.style.color = "black"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You might wanna execute this code before document ready so you don't get a flash from light to dark mode. Also cookies might be blocked by the user.

Comment: @Reyno fixed these problems thank you for noticing

Answer (score 1):

You can easily store that dark mode is on or not in localStorage.

```js
localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).